# Fixtures issue after upgrading to rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to upgrade my app to rails 3.1 and hit an issue while running my tests.

Every test is failing with this error:

```
      NameError: uninitialized constant Fixtures
```

It's coming from using Fixtures.identify() in my fixtures:

```
     <%= Fixtures.identify(:thing) %>
```

Is this no longer supported in rails 3.1? Is there an alternative to using Fixtures.identify to get the ID of a fixture?

Comment: You may have to refer to it as `ActiveRecord::Fixtures` now.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You will have to refer to it as `ActiveRecord::Fixtures` now.